# Why isn't there an Open Source Vmware Vagrant Plugin?

Tags: ruby, plugins, vagrant, virtual-machine, vmware

I was reading up on some vagrant and come to the realization that in order to use vagrant on top of either workstation or fusion, you are required to adquire a license on top of the one for the vmware products.

I found one github repo for an open source plugin providing vmware connectivity, but it was somewhat outdated, which lead me to the question: Why isn´t it such a plugin? Is because of licenses and that kinda stuff, or is it just because those who need to use vagrant + vmware are "happy" to pay the plugin?

Don´t misunderstand me, this question comes from equal parts of genuine curiosity and an inability to adquire said license at the moment (i´m just starting playing with vagrant after all).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: People don't really use vmware with Vagrant, so it isn't popular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There reason is due to [VMWare SDK restrictive license (2008)](http://www.cio.com/article/2433872/virtualization/do-vmware-sdk-license-limits-make-third-party-developers-into-outlaws-.html)

> The problem is that the language in the EULA for VMware's software
>   developers kit (SDK) makes it almost impossible to create for-fee
>   software using any of the SDKs provided by VMware.

Perhaps due to Vagrant popularity, Hashigroup able to acquire some rights from VMWare to build the plugin. I assume there is no free lunch from Vmware.

[you can read the new EULA here](https://www.vmware.com/download/eula/horizon_vse_sdk_eula.htmlf)

> You are permitted to re-distribute the "distributable code" and the
>   modified or derivative works of the "modifiable code" only as part of
>   your Developer Software for non-commercial or commercial use; provided
>   that you shall only distribute such code subject to a license
>   agreement that protects VMware™s and its licensors™ interests
>   consistent with the terms contained in this Agreement

.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer! Just to clarify, does that means that I can't develop a VMWare vagrant plugin with no cost (neither to me nor the ones who would use it) or that i have to include some kind of license/agreement in said plugin in order to make it compliant with VMWare EULA ? 
It's my first time with licences and stuff, so I'm sorry if theres something I;m missing.

Comment: @RamaRivera  You must contact VMware, there is no other way to comply with the EULA.